# How to set the orientation of the PageView to the left?

Tags: flutter

I have to add pages dynamically at left side.

So, is it possible to set a PageView whose default orientation is horizontal and left, like the orientation of a Japanese book?

If initial List of pages is like:

```
List<Widget> _pages = [Widget0, Widget1, Widget2];
```

Plain PageView's direction:

```
[0] -> [1] -> [2]
```

But what I want:

```
[2] <- [1] <- [0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `PageView` documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html), under the properties section you could try using the `reverse` property, here's a brief example:

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return PageView(
      reverse: true,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list before you send it to `pageview`

Example:

```
_pages.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `_pages.add()` use:

```
_pages.insert(0,Widget())
```

that means to insert a new widget dynamically to the list of widgets but at first index.

Comment: I tried this, but I had the same problem with caveat in this first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52579301/adding-new-pages-to-a-pageview-while-swiping

Comment: Yeah right, then you should go with reverse: true answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well, I guess the perfect way to dynamically add pages on both sides is unknown yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property reverse which is available in the PageView.

```
return PageView(
  reverse: true,
  children: [
    Center(
      child: Text('Page 1'),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text('Page 2'),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text('Page 3'),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Please review @Tim’s answer for a good example of how to answer questions like this.